# BeautifulSoup Web Scraping - Can't access and extract element

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

this is my first question at stack overflow.
I am working on a web scraping project and I try to access html elements with beautiful soup.

Please can someone give me advice how to extract the following elements?

The task is to scrape all job listings from a search result page.

The job listing elements are inside the "ResultsSectionContainer".

I want to access each "article class" and

1. extract its id e.g job-item-7460756
2. extract its href where data-at="job-item-title"
3. extract its h2 text (solved)

How to loop through the ResultsSectionContainer and access/extract the information for each 'article class' element / id job-item ?

The name of the article class is somehow dynamic/unique and changes (I guess) every time a new search is done.

```
<div class="ResultsSectionContainer-gdhf14-0 cxyAav">\n 
 <article class="sc-fzowVh cUgVEH" id="job-item-7460756">
  <a class="sc-fzoiQi eRNcm" data-at="job-item-title" 
    href="/stellenangebote--Wirtschaftsinformatiker-m-w-d-mit-Schwerpunkt-ERP-Systeme-Heidelberg-Celonic-Deutschland-GmbH-Co-KG--7460756-inline.html" target="_blank">\n
    <h2 class="sc-fzqARJ iyolKq">\n  Wirtschaftsinformatiker (m/w/d) mit Schwerpunkt ERP-Systeme\n                
        </h2>\n               
        </a>\n              
  
  <article class="sc-fzowVh cUgVEH" id="job-item-7465958">\n
   ...
```

Comment: Please post the URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this.

- Select the `<div>` with class name as `ResultsSectionContainer-gdhf14-0`
- Find all the `<article>` tags inside the above `<div>` using `.find_all()`- *This will give you a list of all article tags*
- Iterate over the above list and extract the data you need.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = '''<div class="ResultsSectionContainer-gdhf14-0 cxyAav">
 <article class="sc-fzowVh cUgVEH" id="job-item-7460756">
  <a class="sc-fzoiQi eRNcm" data-at="job-item-title" 
    href="/stellenangebote--Wirtschaftsinformatiker-m-w-d-mit-Schwerpunkt-ERP-Systeme-Heidelberg-Celonic-Deutschland-GmbH-Co-KG--7460756-inline.html" target="_blank">
    <h2 class="sc-fzqARJ iyolKq">  Wirtschaftsinformatiker (m/w/d) mit Schwerpunkt ERP-Systeme
        </h2>
        </a>
  
  </div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')
d = soup.find('div', class_='ResultsSectionContainer-gdhf14-0')
for i in d.find_all('article'):
    job_id = i['id']
    job_link = i.find('a', {'data-at': 'job-item-title'})['href']
    print(f'JOB_ID: {job_id}\nJOB_LINK: {job_link}')
```

```
JOB_ID: job-item-7460756
JOB_LINK: /stellenangebote--Wirtschaftsinformatiker-m-w-d-mit-Schwerpunkt-ERP-Systeme-Heidelberg-Celonic-Deutschland-GmbH-Co-KG--7460756-inline.html
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast reply. This solution helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If all article classes are same try this

```
articles = data.find_all("article", attrs={"class": "sc-fzowVh cUgVEH"})

for article in articles:
    print(article.get("id"))
    print(article.a.get("href"))
    print(article.h2.text.strip())
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. The class name "sc-fzowVh cUgVEH" is subject of change. It seems that it might not work if I want to apply this code on future search results.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
results = soup.findAll('article', {'class': 'sc-fzowVh cUgVEH'})

for result in results:
    id = result.attrs['id']
    href = result.find('a').attrs['href']
    h2 = result.text.strip()
    
    print(f' Job id: \t{id}\n Job link: \t{href}\n Job desc: \t{h2}\n')
    print('---')
```

you may also want to prefix `href` with the url where you're pulling the results from.